# Track/Log crashes that might occur on client-side for my chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, error-handling, google-analytics

I have a chrome extension that will be released soon. This question is not for debugging purposes but rather a way to track or log crashes/errors that might happen on the clients once it has been released.

I want to be able to get enough information to be able to reproduce the crashes/errors like,  browser version, steps taken in the application to get the error/crash etc..

Searching online for a while but did not find anything concrete about once it has been released. Most of them was for debugging purposes when still in development mode.

I found this https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_analytics but this was more for normal analytics to see what parts of the extension is being used etc.. i am looking more for error handling. Like some games have `"send crash report"`. Looking for somebody to point me in the right direction.

Comment: There's no extensions API to detect a crash or send an info about it. Chrome 72 will ship [Reporting API](https://github.com/w3c/reporting/blob/master/EXPLAINER.md) that can send a crash info.

Comment: Thank you for the information

Comment: @wOxxOm do you know if it will work specifically with chrome extensions?